# Passing props that is an array to 2 different components

Tags: vue-component

This is my 3rd day working with Vue CLI, and I want to pass props that is an array to 2 different components. The components are called Products and Modal. The Modal component is dependent on the Products component. When I pass props to both components inside my App.vue, I don't want both components to render in my App.vue. Like I said, my Modal component is dependent on my Products component.

My overall goal is to display the product title, photo, and description in my modal.

The issue I have is I make a get request in my App.vue, which i fill an empty array and then pass that to Products component. If i pass the array as props to both Products and Modal, I will get an extra modal to render at app level which does make sense, but I don't want that.

Im still getting used to how Vue works and tips or help would be much appreciated.

This could be a very obvious answer that i'm just overlooking, but i'm learning, so please understand that.

App.Vue (I make my get request here and fill an empty array to then have that array passed down as props to the two components):

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <all-products v-bind:newProductsArray="newProductsArray"></all-products>
</div>
</template>

<script>
//imports
import Vue from 'vue'
import AllProducts from './components/AllProducts.vue'
import Modal from './components/Modal.vue'
//import so I can use vue resource for an http request
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(VueResource)

    //export components to be rendered by main.js then by the DOM
    export default {
      components: {
        'all-products': AllProducts
      },
      data() {
        return {
          //empty products array to be filled after get request
          products: [],
          //declare new array to be set to products array, then passed as props. I do this because without another array,
          //all products component will receiev an empty array before it can be filled by the http request.
          newProductsArray: []
        }
      },
      //request to retrieve all products from API using Created
      created() {
        //http request using vue resource from dependencies
        this.$http.get('https://tap-on-it-exercise-backend.herokuapp.com/products').then(function(data) {
          //fill products array by grabbing the data, slicing ot, then setting it to products array
          this.products = data.body.slice(0, data.body.length)
          //set products array to the new array to be passed down as props to all products component.
          this.newProductsArray = this.products
        })
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Product component (This component receives props from app.vue):

```
<template>
<div class="products">
  <h1 class="all-products">All Products</h1>
  <div v-for="product in newProductsArray" :key="product.id" class="single-product">
    <div class="product-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 center-block">
          <div class="title">{{product.title}}</div>
          <img class="images" :src="product.photo_url">
          <div class="price">${{product.price}}</div>
          <modal/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
//imports
import Vue from 'vue'
import Modal from './Modal.vue'
//import bootstrap to be used to style buttons and modal.
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

export default {
  //receive new products array as props from app
  props: ['newProductsArray'],
  components: {
    'modal': Modal
  },

  data() {
    return {
      //set modal show to false by default
      modalShow: false
    }
  },

  methods: {

    showModal() {
      //toggle modal to show
      this.modalShow = true
    },

    closeModal() {
      //toggle modal to close
      this.modalShow = false
    }

  },

}
</script>
```

Modal component (I want to receive the same props that products received)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button @click="modalShow = !modalShow">Show Product Info</b-button>
    <b-modal v-model="modalShow" title="title">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="img-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;" src="http://placehold.it/300x340" alt="">
    </div>
      <p class="product-description">Description</p>
      <div slot="modal-footer" class="w-100">
        <b-button size="md" class="float-right" variant="warning" @click="modalShow=false">Close</b-button>
        <b-button size="md" class="float-right" variant="primary" @click="modalShow=false">Like</b-button>
      </div>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['newProductsArray'],
    data() {
      return {
        modalShow: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: inside my products component where i add a modal to each product can i do this to pass props to the modal?  <modal v-bind:newProductsArray="newProductsArray"></modal>

Comment: figured it out, the solution was to pass props in my products component that looks like this: <modal v-bind:product="product"></modal>, then in my modal component i receive props through my export default as props: ['product']. then whatever i want to use inside my product, i can refer to in my modal.